# Distributing Records Evenly From One Table to Another

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables:

```
Users
-----
UserID (varchar)
Active (bit)

Refunds_Upload 
--------------
BorrowerNumber (varchar)

Refunds
-------
BorrowerNumber 
UserID
```

I first select all of the UserID values where Active = 1.

I need to insert the records from Refunds_Upload to Refunds but **I need to insert the same (or as close as possible) number of records for each Active UserID**.
For example, if Refunds_Upload has 20 records and the Users table has 5 people where Active = 1, then I would need to insert 4 records per UserID into table Refunds.

End Result would be:

```
BorrowerNumber  UserID
105             Fred
110             Fred
111             Fred
115             Fred
120             Billy
122             Billy
123             Billy
125             Billy
130             Lucius
131             Lucius
133             Lucius
135             Lucius
138             Lucy
139             Lucy
140             Lucy
141             Lucy
142             Grady
143             Grady
144             Grady
145             Grady
```

Of course, it won't always come to an even number of records per User so I need to account for that as well.

Comment: in your end result why BorrowerNumber  for each user is not same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First run this and check it returns something like what you want to insert, before you uncomment the insert and actually carry it out..

```
--INSERT INTO Refunds

SELECT
  numbered_u.UserID,
  numbered_ru.BorrowerNumber
FROM
  (SELECT u.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UserID) - 1 as rown, SUM(CAST(Active as INT)) OVER() as count_users FROM Users u WHERE active=1) numbered_u
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT ru.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BorrowerNumber) - 1 as rown, COUNT(*) OVER() as count_ru FROM Refund_Uploads ru) numbered_ru
  ON
    ROUND(CAST(numbered_ru.rown AS FLOAT) / (count_ru / count_users)) = numbered_u.rown
```

The logic:

We number every interesting (active=1) row in users and we also count them all. This should return us all 5 users, numbered 0 to 4 and with a ctr that is 5 on each row.

Then we join them to a similarly numbered list of Refund_Uploads (say 20). Similarly, those rows will be numbered 0 to 19 for mathematical reasons that become apparent later. We also count all these rows too

And we then join these two datasets together but the condition is a range of values rather than exact values. The logic is "refund_upload row number, divided by the_count_of_rows_there_should_be_per_user" (i.e. 0..19 / (20/5) ) = user_row_number. Hopefully thus refund rows 0 to 3, associate with user 0, refund rows 4 thru 7 associate with user 1.. etc

It's a little hard to debug without full data - I feel it might need a few +1 / -1 tweaks here and there.

I originally used FLOOR but switched to using ROUND, as I think this might work for distributing sets of numbers where there isn't a whole number of divisions in Refund/User e.g. your 240/13 example.. Hopefully some users will have 18 rows and some 19

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm seeing: Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
The column prefix 'u' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'numbered_u'.

Comment: Fixed, sorry.. That was a aliasing problem on  the inner queries

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting this back now: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Operand data type bit is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: Well I never knew that.. Modified the query so it converts bit to an integer

Comment: Thanks. This is really working well except for 1 small flaw.  I'm testing with 240 records in Refunds_Upload and 13 users in the Users table.  The query accurately produces 18 records per user (18*13 = 234) but then 6 records get orphaned and never accounted for.  Is there a way to round up so some would get 19 and some 18 in this example?